# CanCan Gem - How to get cancan to deny access for missing resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Ive the following in my Gemfile

```
gem 'cancan', '1.6.4'
```

Im able to use cancan well except in the situation of missing resource. Lets say Ive a resource User, access to which is protected by CanCan.

So my ability.rb file has

```
can :manage, User, :user_id => @user.id
```

This works great in that users can only manipulate their own profile - if you try to manage someone else' profile cancan will throw a`CanCan::AccessDenied`

However if someone is fishing for accounts and starts using random user ids to get access to user info as an example tries hitting `http://myserver.com/users/100` and if the user with id 100 does not exist then there is an error as cancan cannot even find the record for user with id=100.

This is not graceful - Id like cancan to still throw the `CanCan::AccessDenied` exception so that

1. The user experience is better
2. My exception_logger db is not crammed full of exceptions when someone is fishing
3. I dont get notifications for this

In effect I want cancan to deny access for missing resource

Any pointers are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this but I think you can probably put a global exception handler in place that handles the ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound and throws the desired exception instead.

Something like this in your application controller might work:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) {
    raise(CanCan::AccessDenied, 'Invalid access request')
  }
end
```

Comment: I think Im also going to check if the current action is 'show' and the exceptions is ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. Also wondering if there are any unintended consequences of doing this ?

Comment: I think maybe the safe and neat way to do this is to put in exeption handling for both RecordNotFound and AccessDenied and get them to display the same generic error page.  That should give the standardised user experience you're looking for.